# How do I add a pattern/img/graphic for the navbar in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, design-patterns

Here is my html of the navbar:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <!-- <div class="container"> -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT ME<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
               <!--  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li> -->
              </ul>
            <li><a href="#lifeskilz">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

-->

Here is my custom css:

```
.navbar-wrapper .container {
/*background image will not show up error*/
height: 68px;
background-image: url('../img/pinkPattern.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x 0 100%;
```

}

The height changes just fine but I am receiving this error msg regarding the css:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. It seems to be conflicting with 
script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js but i don't know what to do.
Please help, ive been trying to figure this out for 2 days now.

Thanks

Comment: `background-repeat` should be just `repeat-x`, I think you have put something else with it

Comment: I tried that and it still does not work. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Is there a link or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to check the issue?

Comment: Thanks you guys, i figured it out, i was targeting the wrong element, thanks again